# Installing gosu on Mac OS X

Tags: ruby, macos, libgosu

I'm trying to install gosu on my Mac. I used the command:

```
sudo gem install gosu
```

After I enter my password, I get something that says:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
```

However, then it comes up with this error:

```
ERROR: Error installing gosu:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
```

Does anyone have any ideas to fix this? I don't know why it would be saying this.

Comment: Do you have the x-code command line tools and cocoapods installed? Are you using a version manager (rbenv/rvm), or just system gems?

Comment: Please review SO markdown to avoid using <br /> tags to style your posts. http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: That error is often associated with a library dependency that is not met, can you verify those dependencies are installed?

Comment: Sorry guys it turned out I solved it. I just kept googling the error, and found some website that told me to do something, and a different website that told me to do another thing, and they worked.

Comment: Could you read back over those links and figure out what you changed, and write it up as a quick answer referencing the links? It'd help in the future for people having trouble with Gosu on Mac.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
sudo gem install gosu
```

if that still does not work, then do the following

```
- install Homebrew (google it)
- run brew install sdl2.
- run sudo gem install gosu
```

If that still doesn't work, then try to see if you can get an answer from [here](https://github.com/gosu/gosu/wiki/Getting-Started-on-OS-X)

Hope that helps!